# Show only modified files in Finder

Tags: mac, file-management, osx-mountain-lion

Is there any way to make Finder in Mac to only show files that were recently updated within a particular folder?

I'm working on a web project and there are lots of loose HTML files that are nested within subfolders. I'm wondering if there is something similar like GitTower where it will show only the files that were recently modified before committing them to a repo. I would set it up on VC, but we don't have access to the server and I have to ZIP up and send them the updated files.

Comment: If you can ignore subfolders, you could use a Saved Search.  Or skip the UI and just use a `find` expression in Terminal to zip only files modified since a particular date.

Answer (score 2):

When you start typing in the search bar in Finder you get a small bar just below the search bar. On the far right is a plus button. It is just left of a Save button. Press the plus button and you will see a filter show up just below and on the left. One of the options is `Last modified date`. Select that and then choose `within last`. Then give it the range you want.

You also want to be sure that the search is limited to your selected folder. On my Mac this is the default, but that is a Finder setting. On the same bar as the original *plus* button you will have some buttons on the left. One of them is the current folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is the following: in Finder select View > Arrange By > Date Modified.

Comment: Yeah, that will arrange them to so which ones were modified, but I'm looking to have it show only the files that were modified recently. Plus, finder won't necessarily show the files that were modified buried within sub-folders.